# Traps on Stone Path decoration

Tags: clash-of-clans, clash-of-clans-builder-base

On the "Builder Base" in Clash of Clans, can hidden traps (mines, push traps, spring traps, etc.) be placed *on top of* the "stone path" decoration? And, if so, are the stones still visible to attackers?

(I ask the second part because it appears that traps can be placed on top of "tall grass" obstacles without removing the grass first, but when viewing my own base, the grass obstacle is no longer visible when a trap is placed on it.)

**Update**
It looks like when a trap is placed on top of the "tall grass" obstacle, the obstacle is completely removed from the base when the trap is moved and placed elsewhere. Possibly a bug?

Comment: Interesting find... Tried this seems like a bug. If you place a trap on "Tall Grass" the obstacle is replaced with trap. This happens only with Tall Grass.... On the flipside easier way to remove Tall Grass from base :P

Comment: The bug has been fixed in subsequent updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any 2x2 trap cannot be placed on a stone path at all, and any 1x1 trap will just displace the stone path if you try to put it onto it. This also works if you try to put/move a stone paths onto a trap.

Comment: That's what I was expecting.  Thanks for confirming it!